# Change the wp-content directory

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm using wordpress. How to change the wp-content directory for all my theme, including the inactive themes?

I used:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/new-wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'url_to_mysite/new-wp-content');
```

But the paths for the inactived theme do not change.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on this,

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/renaming-wordpress-wp-content-folder/

Hope this helps you

Comment: Can you summarize the article? We collect solutions, not links to solutions ;)